# Cannot retrieve value from sql query

Tags: php, sql

My query not return any value.

```
$minprice = itemDetails("SELECT MIN(extra_night) FROM hotel_room WHERE hotel_id ='".$row[hotel_id]."'");
```

Below is my site

https://www.borneoecotours.com/hotels/index--.php

```
<?php 
            //$sql_query = $querystring;

            $j=0;
            if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbhandler,$querystring)) > 0){ //if there is a record
                $sql_result = mysqli_query($dbhandler,$querystring)or die(mysqli_error());                      
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)){

                    echo '<div class="summbox">';
                    echo '<div class="summheader">';
                    echo '<div class="summtitle"><a href="view.php?id='.$row[hotel_id].'" class="hotlink">'.$row[code].' : '.stripslashes($row[name]).'&nbsp;';                     
                        for ($x=1; $x<=$row[star]; $x++){echo "<span class='icon-star blue'></span>";}
                    echo '</a></div>';
                    echo '<div class="summduration">'.$row[location].', '.ucwords($row[region]).'</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<br clear="right" />';
                    echo '<div class="summcenter">';
                    if ($row[pic]==""){
                        echo '<div class="summpic"><img src="image/'.$row[hotel_id].'/profile.jpg" width="200" height="150" /></div>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<div class="summpic"><img src="../image/tours/'.$row[pic].'" width="200" height="150" /></div>';
                    }                   
                    echo '<div class="summdetails">'.stripslashes($row[brief]).'</div>';
                    $minprice = itemDetails("SELECT MIN(extra_night) FROM hotel_room WHERE hotel_id ='".$row[hotel_id]."'");
                    echo '<div class="summprice" style="width:250px;">RATES FROM <br />MYR <span style="font-size:20px;">'.$minprice.'</span></div>';
                    echo '<br clear="right" />';
                    echo '<div class="summfooter">';
                    echo '<a href="view.php?id='.$row[hotel_id].'" class="button small blue">Details</a>&nbsp;'; //details                  
                    if ($row[hotel_id] != '17')
                        echo '<a href="form.php?id='.$row[hotel_id].'" class="button small red">Book Now</a>'; //enquiry
                    else
                        echo '<a href="http://www.borneobackpackers.com/reservation.php" class="button small red">Book Now</a>'; //enquiry
                    //echo '<a href="#"><div class="summbutton_03"></div></a>'; //booknow
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="clear">';

                }
            } else{
                echo '<div class="alert-msg error">No record. Please search again.</div>';
            }
        ?>
```

Supposed to be the $minprice will return the value form my database. Any idea?
The output should shown MYR (value from database),Example: MYR 1200

```
function itemDetails($query){
$sql_query = mysql_query($query);
$item = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query);
return stripslashes($item[0]);
```

}

Comment: May be this `$row[star]` ==> `$row['star']` . I mean access row values specifying `column` value as `string`.

Comment: I dont  get it @Jyothi. I mean the value still shown from my column. My only problem is the price. It wont show from my database. Do u have any idea ?

Comment: What your `itemDetails` function doing there? update it here

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja you can see the function above.. thanks

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Thank you so much! I manage to display the price now.